# Using Index & Match in Excel; why don't named ranges work?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that I am using to summarize some data from other tables; the data is almost entirely text so a pivot table isn't the answer.  I have a table on a worksheet as follows...
[image: [Screenshot]]

Here is a typical formula for columns D:L...
FORMULA: `=INDEX(tblITPM,MATCH(tblHCSmry[[#Headers],[Data Source]],tblITPM[[#All],[Column1]],0),MATCH([@MetricName],'SheetA'!$A$2:$D$2,0))`

Individally, the formulae seem to work fine but the total of the calculations only works in the first 3 rows of my summary table (tblHCSmry).  There are two issues that I don't know how to solve:

1. In the "array" section of the `INDEX` I am referencing table
   names that are listed in column B (TableName); hard-coding like I
   have above (tblTableA) makes all of the items that need to reference
   a separate table on a separate worksheet to fail.
2. The `MATCH` formula (`MATCH([@MetricName],'1_ITPM_Summary'!$A2:$D2,0)`) have a similar issue; I get the correct answer for the first 3 tables (2, 3, or 4) which I expect since the "lookup_array" is hard-coded.  So, the issue again arises though when I want to reference a different table such as tblTableB by pointing to Column B of tblHCSmry.

I suppose the main question is: can I use a named range of a table, or do I need to use the "'SheetA'!A3:D3" format?  If so, is there a way to dynamically change, "'SheetA'!" to "'SheetB'!" by referencing Column B of the tblHCSmry? FWIW: I tried to CONCATENATE the Sheet name with the reference and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use named ranges, but you'd need to have pointers to the location of the data in cells, which appears to be what you already have in Columns A and B. You can then reference those dynamically using using `=INDIRECT()`. `=INDIRECT()` allows you to take a value of a cell and use that as a reference as opposed to the reference being to the cell itself.

For instance

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT([@TableName]),MATCH(tblHCSmry[[#Headers],[Data Source]],tblITPM[[#All],[Column1]],0),MATCH([@MetricName],INDIRECT("'" & [@TabName] & "'!$A$2:$D$2"),0))
```

Would make your return array whatever is referenced in `[@TableName]`, and your array parameter in your second `MATCH` function would be whatever is referenced in `[@TabName]`

MSDN has very basic documentation of [INDIRECT()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) here, but there's quite a bit you can accomplish with it as far as creating more dynamic formulas.

Comment: thanks, works perfectly. One question: how do I use that with Columns to fix the the 2nd part of the first MATCH formula?

Comment: Same way. You'd have to define the parameters as cell values that you can then reference using INDIRECT. If you're trying to dynamically reference different columns in the worksheets from TabName you'd have to change `tblITPM[[#All],[Column1]]` to `INDIRECT("'" & [@TabName] & "'!" & [@ReferenceToColumn])` The ReferenceToColumn would be a column you'd have to add to your current table.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Tate: can you explain, or provide reference to, why INDIRECT works and CONCATENATE doesn't?

Comment: The tooltip for `INDIRECT` explains that it "returns the reference specified by a text string", meaning that instead of referencing a cell and returning a value directly, you're creating a string inside `INDIRECT` which will then reference whatever your string specifies. The reason `CONCATENATE` doesn't work is because its just a function for returning a string value of the directly referenced cells. `INDIRECT` and `CONCATENATE` are functionally different fundamentally. That being said, you _can_ use `CONCATENATE` inside of `INDIRECT` to create your string reference.

Comment: If you want an example of how they're different, try
`=INDIRECT("A0")` versus `=CONCATENATE("A","0")` and see what you get. `INDIRECT` will throw a `#REF` error because `A0` is not a referable range, where `CONCATENATE` will return "A0" because it's just returning a concatenated string of the parameters within.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.